# Duplicated records in Yii2 GridView

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

It was working just fine, but I had to import data afresh in the existing `order1` table which is related to `order_item` table on `order.id = order_item.order_id` and `order_item.location_id = location.id`

So to get the location in GridView of `order1` table I had relation defined like so:

```
public function getLocation() {         
    return $this->hasOne(Location::className(), ['id' => 'location_id'])->viaTable('{{%order_item}}', ['order_id' => 'id']);            
}
```

Now I have multiple records in the GridView. The query formed for the GridView is like:

```
SELECT `order1`.* 
FROM `order1` 
    LEFT JOIN `order_item` ON `order1`.`id` = `order_item`.`order_id`
    LEFT JOIN `location` ON `order_item`.`location_id` = `location`.`id` 
where 1 ORDER BY `id` DESC 
LIMIT 20;
```

How I can fix this as inner join or otherwise, so that it returns records only once from `order1` table?

In GridView I am using `location.location_title`.

Note: there are multiple order items per order.

**also Tried:**

```
public function getOrderItem()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::className(), ['order_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getLocation()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Location::className(), ['id' => 'location_id'])
        ->via('orderItem');
}
```

Comment: You can add group by `order1.id`. But it really looks like your relation is incorrect (it shouldn't be `hasOne()` if you can have multiple relations through `order_item`).

Comment: yes you are right. but whether I mention `hasOne` or `hasMany` the result is same. where I can use group by in the above query?

Comment: I have added the alternative relation query in the question.

Comment: I have added in `OrderSearch` like `$query->joinWith(['location'])->groupBy('id');` is this correct? as I am getting the result as expected. Thanks rob006

Comment: Just add `->groupBy('order.id')` in your `getLocation()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `GROUP BY` in your search model to ensure that orders will not be duplicated in query results:

```
$query->groupBy('order1.id');
```

Although `hasOne()` seems to be incorrect (if one order can have multiple items, then it could also have multiple locations), changing this to `hasMany()` will not fix GridView results. You need to be careful with one-to-many or many-to-many relations, usually you need to use `GROUP BY` to remove duplicates or adjust your DB structure or joins in search model, to avoid such situation.

---

BTW: Adding `groupBy()` in relation definition (`getLocation()`) is almost always incorrect. This is not a job of relation definition to handle grouping of main model results (you can be almost sure it will create issues with lazy loading).

Comment: Thanks Rob - as I mentioned in comments, I have added groupBy in searchModel and not in relation and that is working fine. coming to `hasOne()` and 'hasMany()` the first relation is certainly `hasMany()` that is many `orderItem` against one order, but each `orderItem` can have just one `location`, so how should I go about it, I am using the first query in my question that is `viaTable`. so when checking the effects, if I am using `hasMany` my location column in gridview returns `not set` and while using `hasOne` it is correctly returning the `location`

Comment: You should use relation type in context of main model - if `Order` model can have multiple locations, you should use `hasMany()` in `Order::getLocations()` relation. `hasOne()` may work, but it will just return random location from list of locations available through order items.

Comment: Hi Rob - I don't have direct relationship between `Order` Model and `location` model. I need to get it though `orderItem` model, but you are right, suppose one order has five orderItem and each item having different location, then which location it will return. I think providing `location` info in order gridview is wrong basically or to provide `all locations` pertaining to that order in comma separated way.

Comment: Hi Rob - can you please take a look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59897322/yii2-mogodb-rbac-configuration